# Minimize / miniaturize cocoa NSWindow without titlebar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm stuck!  Obviously... because I'm posting a question here.

I have built my own custom window controls for my OS X / cocoa app.  The close button works great -- no problems.  The minimize button doesn't work at all when I disable the titlebar.

[image]

So when the title bar is on like the image above and I hit this method, the minimizing works fine:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController {

    - (IBAction)minimize:(id)sender;        
    @property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *btn_minimize;

}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (IBAction)minimize:(id)sender {
      [[NSApp mainWindow] performMiniaturize:self];
    }

    -(IBAction)terminate:(id)sender {
        [NSApp terminate:self];
    }
@end
```

Then if I disable the title bar, that same method stops working.  No errors, nothing.  I've tried both: `[[NSApp mainWindow] miniaturize:nil];` and also `[[NSApp mainWindow] performMiniaturize:self];`.  Neither of which worked.  Actually... the both work IF the title bar is on.  But once I turn it off, neither work.

[image: titlebar turned off]

[image: app with no title bar]

Thoughts / comments?

Oh, I'm using Storyboards, Xcode 7, and am targeting 10.10 and using the 10.11 SDK if that matters at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you disable/hide it what is the status of main menu bar (there should be validation, which means unsupported menu items are greyed out). If they are clickable do they work? (are they calling your viewController?)

Comment: [NSWindow performMiniaturize:] calls [minimizeButton performClick:esi], +[NSWindow _minimizeAll]: calls [ebx standardWindowButton:0x1] isEnabled] != 0x0) && ([ebx isVisible] != 0x0). Manual override calls private _minimizeToDock. This means if you want them to work, either you use private selectors or dislay those buttons

Comment: Do you want to leave those buttons at this location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to keep the original "traffic light" buttons around and hide them manually.

Here's how I've configured the window:

```
self.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
self.movableByWindowBackground = YES;
```

And here's how I've hidden the traffic lights:

```
for (id subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSTitlebarContainerView")]) {
        NSView *titlebarView = [subview subviews][0];
        for (id button in titlebarView.subviews) {
            if ([button isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) {
                [button setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[See sample project here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Custom%20Window%20Controls.zip).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to completely remove the title bar and trigger the miniaturization through some other means (eg: a key assignment).

I found that ensuring that the window style mask includes `NSMiniaturizableWindowMask` was required in order for `NSWindow::miniaturize` to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Wez Furlong's answer, this is how to do it in Swift 5.

Assuming you have an NSWindow named "theWindow", do the following:

```swift
theWindow.styleMask = theWindow.styleMask.union(.miniaturizable)
```

Basically, you perform a set union of the window's existing style mask with the .miniaturizable option.