# Mac OS low-level window framework

Tags: macos, window, appkit

Currently I use AppKit's NSWindow to create windows. The problem is that it has a lot of "default behaviour"/limitations. For example: [miniaturize does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045075/minimize-miniaturize-cocoa-nswindow-without-titlebar) if there is no titlebar (also I have some troubles with borderless window, with corner radius and etc.).

I understand that this "default behaviour" is good in most cases, but not in my.

Is there any low-level window API (C/C++/Obj-C) for Mac OS? I don't need any Views, controls and etc. All I need - area to draw and source of events.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `NSWindow` and implement your custom behavior on top of it. The best way to achieve that would be to create your own subclass of `NSWindow` and override the behaviors you want. This sample code creates a `NSWindow` which has no titlebar, has rounded corners and can be miniaturized:

```
@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow

@end

@implementation CustomWindow

- (instancetype)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)style backing:(NSBackingStoreType)backingStoreType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSWindowStyleMask effectiveStyle = style | NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:effectiveStyle backing:backingStoreType defer:NO];

    self.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
    self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;

    self.movableByWindowBackground = YES;

    [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = YES;
    [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = YES;
    [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = YES;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: For me, the system buttons are hidden, but the space is still being taken up by them, because my toolbar starts from where they would end. Is there some way of having them removed completely?

Comment: Never mind.. I found that setting `styleMask` to exclude `NSWindowStyleMaskClosable` etc works